Installing template dependencies using npm... npm error code ERESOLVE
i'm trying to make
npx create-react-app calc-app
everything was installed correctly but this appear
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: calc-app@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\ariana\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-18T14_26_32_953Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ariana\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-18T14_26_32_953Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed

so i try to run ´npm install´
and this was the message
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall open
npm error path C:\Users\ariana\Documents\Cursos\React\package.json
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ariana\Documents\Cursos\React\package.json'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ariana\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-18T14_30_41_989Z-debug-0.log

idk what else do

One of the dependencies (@testing-library/react@13.4.0 expects react@~18.0.0), which is incompatible with the React version (react@19.0.0), is the cause of this problem. This is how to repair it:
The --legacy-peer-deps flag should be used: To get around the dependency resolution problem, run the npx create-react-app command once again with this flag:
npx create-react-app calc-app --use-npm --legacy-peer-deps

